# QList<QString> to QString.arg()

Tags: qt

I have the following QString:

```
QString funcProxy = "executeProxy(\"%1\", \"%2\", \"%3\")";
```

The data for each on is in:

```
QList<QString> listProxy;
```

How would I go about adding the data in listProxy to funcProxy using the arg() method?

```
funcProxy.arg(??);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the answer from @owacoder, you do not actually need the replace function, the following should work correclty:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listProxy.size(); ++i) {
    funcProxy = funcProxy.arg(listProxy.at(i));
}
```

Why you ask: From the documentation on [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg)

> Returns a copy of this string with the lowest numbered place marker replaced by string

Thus it replaces the lowest number with the string in the arg call. First iteration contains `%1`, `%2` and `%3`, so it replaces `%1`. Next iteration contains `%2` and `%3`, thus replaces `%2`.

Alternatively if you have control over `funcProxy` you can do the following given you can change your list to a `QStringList`:

```
QString funcProxy = "executeProxy(\"%1\")";
QStringList listProxy{"a", "b", "c"};

funcProxy = funcProxy.arg(listProxy.join("\", \""));
```

Comment: The first provided solution with for loop is working, nice job. Only qWarning "QString::arg: Argument missing" appears (it's annoying).

The second solution is not working for me, what am I doing wrong? See the code:
    QStringList args {"a", "b", "c"};
    QString out("%1 - %2 - %3");
    qDebug() << out.arg(args.join("\", \""));

the output is: "a\", \"b\", \"c - %2 - %3"

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll have exactly 3 elements in your list, you can do this:

```
funcProxy.arg(listProxy.at(0)).arg(listProxy.at(1)).arg(listProxy.at(2));
```

Otherwise, you could use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listProxy.size(); ++i)
    funcProxy.replace(QString("%%1").arg(i+1), listProxy.at(i));
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that because it could be more than three.  funcProxy would be different everytime.  It may seem that I would have to loop through it.